# How to not lose accuracy when saving a DataFrame to csv

Tags: python, pandas, floating-accuracy

I have the following DataFrame:

```
      Direction      Date     Market     Quantity     Price      Commission  Charges
0        S        29/12/2020   IBTM    38.46538070  12.242512       0.0        0
1        S        29/12/2020   IDTG  1131.17689270    2.554843      0.0        0
2        S        29/12/2020   SGLN   563.28337820   7.236522       0.0        0
```

df['Quantity'] is a `float64` dtype.

Whenever I save the DataFrame to a .csv file I get the following:

[image]

thus losing some accuracy for some of the values in df['Quantity'].

I already tried the following:

```
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].map(lambda x: '%.8f' % x)
```

and then:

```
df.to_csv(r'/Users/Example.csv', index=False, float_format='%.8f')
```

but I still get the same output. Is there a way to maintain the number of decimals when saving `df.to_csv`?

Comment: Are you sure whatever you are using to show the csv file is not truncating numbers just for visualization? Can you try to see if you have the same decimals by opening the csv with a text editor, e.g. Notepad?

Comment: @Simone Thanks for your comment - the correct amount of decimals are shown when I open the .csv file into a Text Editor. However, the only way to show all decimals in my saved .csv file is to manually increase the decimal places on Excel.

Comment: Ok, so your Python code is doing what you want, it's just a matter of Excel's formatting.